# System Invocation Error when Running Cspade - R

Tags: r

I am trying to run the cspade function in the arulesSequences package in R. After I successfully read in my transactions using read_baskets, I try to execute the cspade function against the transactions object I read in.

However, when I execute the command, I obtain an error: system invocation failed. Specifically, here is the output.

```
 preprocessing ... 1 partition(s), 1.2 MB [0.23s]
 mining transactions ...Error in cspade(table, parameter = list(support = 0.1), control =         list  (verbose = TRUE)) : 
 system invocation failed
```

The presence of "mining transactions" indicates that the following function call in the cspade code is failing.

```
  if (system2(file.path(exe, "spade"), args = c("-i", file, 
  "-s", parameter@support, opt, "-e", nop, "-o"), stdout = out)) 
  stop("system invocation failed").
```

For reference, I can successfully generate sequences using the example zaki dataset.

Does anyone have any idea why that command might be failing?

Thanks,

Stewart

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Sequence_Mining/SPADE#Caveats

See link above, caveats section and lower your support threshold.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem, I decreased the support ( put 0), still didn't work. But came up with another solution:
I changed the data size (less rows) and it works.
so if for example you can devide your data set to 2 parts of half size and make transcation data of each part as x_1 and x_2,

frequent_pattern_1 <- cspade(x_1,parameter = list(support = 0 ))
frequent_pattern_2 <- cspade(x_2,parameter = list(support = 0 ))

then get the absolute support of analysing each dataset to get result of all.

get the absolute support value 
support_x_1<-support(frequent_pattern_1 ,x_1, type= c("absolute"), control = NULL) 
support_x_2<-support(frequent_pattern_2 ,x_2, type= c("absolute"), control = NULL)

then finding the matching sequence and summing the supports of the matched ones.